# how to count number of users click using jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Here is my html code -

```
    <td> 
    <a href="<?php echo $post->js_resume_id;?>" id="play"
    onclick="window.open('/assets/img/videos/assets/<?php echo $post->uploaded_video;?>', 'windowname2',  'width=700, \  height=700');
    return false;">Click to view </a>
    </td>


    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#play").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url().'Employer/view'?>",
                success: function(response) {
                } 
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

I want to count number of users click on  and send number of count to controller.

Comment: maintain a counter variable and increment it on every click.

Comment: what problem did you encountered?

Comment: Either do what you do now, or have `/assets/img/videos/assets/` update a field in the DB

Comment: When you want to send number of click count to controller ? everytime, or after some time ?

Comment: after click on link i want to count number of clicks ,every time

Comment: @Tejaswee Chopde try below code hope you will get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to maintain your click's count using PHP `Session`.The default `session` destroy time is default of `php.ini` file.

When user clicks in the image make the following javascript function with php `session` implemenation.Hope it will work correctly.

```
<td> 
<a href="<?php echo $post->js_resume_id;?>" id="play"
onclick="window.open('/assets/img/videos/assets/<?php echo $post->uploaded_video;?>', 'windowname2',  'width=700, \  height=700');
return false;">Click to view </a>
</td>
```

In this code when user click in Click to view.use `jquery` as below by using `id`play.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#play").click(function(){
                <?php
                    session_start();
                    if(isset($_SESSION['count'])){
                        $_SESSION['count']++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION['count']=1;
                    }

                ?>
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Then to see total number of clicks `echo $_SESSION['count]`. Id your are using the `codeigniter` you can use increase session time using `$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;` session is active until 2 hours if no clicks done.Hope this will help you.Thank you enjoy.....

Comment: i am working on codeigniter , these code will work in codeigniter project

Comment: yes it working very well for me, thank you Hikmat Sijapti

Comment: I just put your php code into my controller function

Comment: lets cheers and enjoy with codeignier...and vote up if you can thank you.